# How to fetch the latest records and status from a group?

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

This is what my data looks like
[image]

You will notice there are 3 groups of rows; only the **createdAt**, **Status** columns are different. I want to fetch the "latest" record from each group, i.e the highlighted rows, with PK = {3,6,9}.

Can this be done with one SQL statement? (dialect is Microsoft SQL Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the row_number feature

```
;with cte
as
(
    select
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RefDocNo ORDER BY CreateAt DESC),
        *
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM cte
        WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

This feature is called Common Table Expression - CTE. It work's just like a subquery except, you can call a cte recursively inside the same. but it is not necessary to name it as cte, instead you can give it any name you like

Comment: It works ! you are a guru and a gentleman lol. just curious what does your abbreviation cte stand for ?

Comment: @joedotnot. I've added more detail on my answer about cte

Answer (score -1):

You have the TOP command in MS SQLSERVER so you can do

```
SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Table WHERE your_where_clauses
      order by your-order-field ASC (DESC IF YOU WANT LAST RECORDS)
)
```

Even if the question is answered with other approach you can achieve the expected result with TOP command.

Hope this helps

Comment: the top 1 only gives one row overall ? In my example, i need 3 rows, are you missing any GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Thats an example, you can adapt inner query to achieve what you want. The important thing is that you want to get last N rows from a query (is the same as N first rows of the same query with inverse order), Notice i set a subselect.  The TOP N command gives you the first N elements of result of the query where it is placed.